# saving zoom scale between viewpager fragments?

Tags: android

I use a viewpager in my app , the pager fragments consist of webview (viewpager of webviews)

The user can zoom in and out in the fragment , the question is how to preserve the zoom scale for the webview to the next or previous page

hope it's clear

Thanks

Comment: How you are doing zoom on fragments ?May i expect to see some code.

Comment: Just like Activities, fragments cycle through certain lifecycle methods. You can try to override f.e. onResume(), to set the zoom factor before displaying the oncoming fragment. Of course, you get this value from the previous fragment, when it did f.e. onPause().